# Can Relative path be provided for -classpath (java)

Tags: java, classpath, relative-path

Can I do this:

```
javac -classpath ././My_Jars/*;././My_Other_Jars/* -d bin Test.java
```

Above command always throws ClassNotfound! (My_Jars not found and My_Other_jars not found)

Java: JDK 6
OS: Windows 7

Comment: Try `javac -classpath ../../My_Jars/*;../../My_Other_Jars/* -d bin Test.java`

Comment: Thanks Bala/Saket for quick reply. Above command with two dots did not work.

Comment: The answer depends on where your jars are relative to your current directory. Whatever the answer, `././` doesn't makes any sense in a path, as `.` refers to "this directory", so there's never a reason to repeat it.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `..` (double dots) rather than `.` (single dot - which refers to current directory) for using relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

The asterisks in a class path is not a wild card but instead tell loads the classes from jar files. If your classes are not in jars then you would just use `<path>/.`

But given your names, I do not think that is the issue. You may want to try:

```
javac -classpath ./../My_Jars/*;./../My_Other_Jars/* -d bin Test.java
```

if your Jars are one level up from the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is not the relative path, but the use of wildcards (the asterixs). These are actually expanded by the command line environment (the shell) - and in this case would not probably give what you are expecting.